# Get Bookmark range

Tags: c#, ms-word, bookmarks

How can i get the range values of each bookmark in my word document? I want them to be shown in datagrid, so the code is:

```
int ii = 0;
Object obj;
var orderedBoomarks = WordDocument.Bookmarks.Cast<Bookmark>().OrderBy(d => d.Start).ToList();
foreach(Bookmark bookmark in orderedBoomarks)
{                    
    obj = bookmark.Range;
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(bookmark.Name.ToString());
    dataGridView1.Rows[ii].Cells[1].Value = obj.ToString();
    ii++;
}
```

For now, the result in cell is "System.__ComObject". So, can i even get the numeric value of bookmark range?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to get the value of the Range, so in this case you can use:

```
string bm = bookmark.Range.Text;
```

Comment: You didnt get me right :) by your way, i'll get the text at the bookmark,so i want to get the number of symbol position at the bookmark. For example: Name: <bookmark>. The number of symbols before the beginning of the <bookmark> is 6

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, ive figured it out:

```
bm_numb =  bookmark.Range.Start;
```

Comment: A word of warning: the number of Range.Start is not particularly reliable/accurate. Word inserts a lot of "hidden" control characters which can throw this off if you try to use it, later. Also field codes can make this inaccurate.